# couting from mysql database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, count

I have a bit of a dilemma. I am trying to grab all of the products from the database that a customer may purchase. However, I have no idea how to write this in c#:

"Keep adding to my 'list' WHILE there is still items in the database that match this order_id."

this is my query string.

```
            productQuery = "SELECT * FROM wdb_orders_products WHERE orders_id = @orders_id";
```

i am completely confused as to what to put in here, that would work for mysql.

```
                while (Reader.Read())
            {
                for(int x=0; x< ??? ; x++)
                db_products[0] = Reader["products_name"].ToString();
            }
```

This is what im trying to grab from the mysql table from the site.

Orders_ID-------Products_Name

52----------------90-96Nissan 300ZX Tail Light

52----------------90-96Nissan 300ZX Bumper

52----------------Some other item

Answer (score -1):

simple example

```
var list = new List<string>();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    list.add(Reader["products_name"].ToString());
 }
```

**BUT i would recommend that you create a Class Product with the Properties you need !**

Comment: I didn't downvote. not sure why.

Im still trying to figure out how to add it to my listbox, and see if it works.

Comment: @AlexMoreno you should set it as `DataSource` like `Listbox1.DataSource =list;` futher informations are [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listbox_members(v=vs.90).aspx)